# how to have a javascript flag reset after a time

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to have some speech occur when a user reaches section of the website:

```
var shutup_theform;
$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
if (!shutup_theform){
    if ($('#theform').isInViewport()) 
        {
            speak_section("send us a message, we would love to hear from you!");
            shutup_theform = true;
        } 
       } });
```

(the *isInViewport* and *speak_section* functions not shown)

I'm using the *shutup_theform* variable to set a flag so that the speech occurs only once.

My question is what would be a suitable way to have this flag reset after a period of time? I'm aware of the setTimeout() function.

Comment: *"I'm aware of the setTimeout() function."* - Yes, `setTimeout()` is what you'd use. If you're already aware of it then what is the question?

Comment: a bit more of a hint would be welcome

Comment: the fact that I'm aware of the setTimeout() function but have posted a question means I'm unsure if this is the best way to go and if it is, then I'm unsure how to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `setTimeout`

```
function resetVar(){
   shutup_theform = false;
}

if ($('#theform').isInViewport()){
    speak_section("send us a message, we would love to hear from you!");
    shutup_theform = true;
    setTimeout(resetVar,time)
  }
```